# Visual Studio 2017 crashes when trying to use MainMenu

Tags: c#, winforms

Can someone tell me why Visual Studio 2017 crashes when I try to use the main menu control?

It doesn't seem to work properly in the designer at all like once I deselect it's completely invisible and I have to select it in the document outline to even be able to edit it.

editing it is the thing that makes visual studio crash though, specifically when adding a new context menu to it.

I have tried importing mainMenu and contextMenu into the designer and using them directly, and have also tried using vistaMenu with no luck.

there is no code but there is a

[image]

I expect it to be editable in the designer.
The only reason I need to use these over the strip versions is they render properly on window 7 which is the version I am using.

Comment: Select it by clicking the component in the tray at the bottom of the designer.  My version of VS2017 has no trouble editing it, I haven't heard of anybody else having this problem.  Try another machine.

Comment: I only have 1 machine, but do you think I might have a corrupt assembly or something it relies on? If so how would I fix it?

Comment: Nobody can give you guidance with such a vague diagnostic.  There will be record of this crash it the Windows event log, not really very helpful either but it is better than nothing.  Starting VS again and using Debug > Attach to attach to the first instance of VS can provide the holy stack trace.  Then again, you can't really ignore the problem with MenuStrip either, it is certainly supposed to render just fine on Win7.  Do get another machine, one is never enough.

Comment: I can try to get a stack trace

Comment: The visual studio 2017 I attached to visual studio 2017 to figure out why it crashed crashed. 0.0 I tried to attach a third one to the second but it said it couldn't. https://imgur.com/AaF6MRJ